# How to create an array of dates in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, date-fns

I am trying to create an array of days, starting from the current day, up to some range that I could modify (for example, 60 days), but I am not succeeding.

Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { add } from 'date-fns'

export const Datepicker = () => {

    const [daysArray, setDaysArray] = useState([ new Date() ]);

    const daysRange = 60;

    useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < daysRange; i++) {
            setDaysArray([ ...daysArray, add(new Date(), { days: i }) ]);
            
        }
        
    }, []);

    console.log(daysArray)
```

I'm waiting for an output like this:

```
0: Mon Nov 07 2022 18:57:14 GMT-0300
1: Tue Nov 08 2022 18:57:14 GMT-0300
2: Wed Nov 09 2022 18:57:14 GMT-0300
3: Thu Nov 10 2022 18:57:14 GMT-0300
Etc... up to the range that I have entered
```

But my output looks like this:

```
0: Mon Nov 07 2022 18:57:14 GMT-0300
1: Thu Jan 05 2023 18:57:14 GMT-0300
```

What am I doing wrong?

I suppose there are better ways to do this than using a for loop, but I really don't know what the best practices are in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`daysArray` has the same value in every iteration

Easy fix:

```
for (let i = 0; i < daysRange; i++) {
  setDaysArray(daysArray => [ ...daysArray, add(new Date(), { days: i }) ]);            
}
```

Better fix:

```
const array = []
for (let i = 0; i < daysRange; i++) {
  array.push(add(new Date(), { days: i }));            
}
setDaysArray(array)
```

Comment: staging 60 `setState` calls shouldn't even be listed as a fix.

Comment: They will be batched in react 18, but yes, it's bad